# Error You provided 'undefined' where a stream was expected. You can provide an Observable, Promise, Array, or Iterable, call refreshSession in Cognito

Tags: angular, amazon-cognito, access-token, interceptor, refresh-token

I'm trying to refresh the access token of a user in AWS Cognito. I'm getting the error: *You provided 'undefined' where a stream was expected. You can provide an Observable, Promise, Array, or Iterable* right after the first time that the method refreshSession is called. I'm using HttpInterceptor in Angular 7. Below is my code:

```
public intercept(request: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
    // process the request
    return next.handle(request).pipe(
        catchError((httpError: any) => {
            // check if the error is a permission issue
            if (httpError instanceof HttpErrorResponse && httpError.status === 401 {
                const poolData = {
                    UserPoolId: <userPoolId>,
                    ClientId: <clientId>
                };
                const userPool = new AmazonCognitoIdentity.CognitoUserPool(poolData);
                const cognitoUser = userPool.getCurrentUser();
                if (cognitoUser != null) {
                    cognitoUser.getSession((error, session) => {
                        if (error) {
                            cognitoUser.signOut();
                            this.router.navigate(['/login']);
                        }
                        cognitoUser.refreshSession(session.refreshToken, (refreshError, refreshSession) => {
                            if (refreshError) {
                                cognitoUser.signOut();
                                this.router.navigate(['/login']);
                            }
                            // set the cognito credentials
                            AWS.config.credentials = new AWS.CognitoIdentityCredentials({
                                IdentityPoolId: this.identityPoolId,
                                Logins: { [`cognito-idp.${<region>}.amazonaws.com/${<userPoolId>}`]: refreshSession.getIdToken().getJwtToken() }
                            });
                            (AWS.config.credentials as AWS.Credentials).refresh(err => {
                                if (err) {
                                    cognitoUser.signOut();
                                    this.router.navigate(['/login']);
                                }
                            });
                        });
                    });
                }
            } else {
                return of(httpError);
            }
        })
    );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Inside your `catchError`, the function returns an observable (`of(httpError)`) only in the `else` clause. There's no return (i.e. *undefined*) if the error is a 401. Return something there, as well, even if you don't care about the return value (in such case, `of(null)` or `EMPTY` should do).